# Prevent brute force password attack in Apache2.2 web server

Tags: apache, security, brute-force, apache2.2

I'm wondering if there is any configuration in Apache2.2 web server to prevent the username from login for few hours after 3 failed login attempts.

I've my all the configurations setup in `default-ssl.conf` file and wanted to configure to prevent the bruit force password attack in this file.

Can anyone provide some idea or any configuration on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [simple way to prevent flood of login requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622952/simple-way-to-prevent-flood-of-login-requests). Anyway [tag:fail2ban].

Comment: but as far as i know in fail2ban file, we can only block IP address not the username. correct me if i'm wrong?